# Should remove old records from a DB?

Tags: database, user-interface

Every time a certain form in a site dashboard loads, I generate a unique ID and store it into the database, when the form is submitted I mark the ID as "used" and don't allow to submit forms which are already used.

Question: Is it worth to store date/time of form load and remove unique IDs say two weeks old?

Or to keep this data in MySQL forever?

Comment: Is it worth it? Who knows? It depends on whether that data will be needed for analysis in the future or not. This is not a programming question - it is a question that the business should answer. If there is no use for the data, then it can _probably_ be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think saving timestamp and clearing out old dara is an excellent idea.

Without that, your web site is not scalable. In fact it could be attacked by repeatedly loading the page and filling your database's disk to capacity, effectively killing your site.

Answer (score 1):

Wether it is worth to store the date-time of the form in the database is up to your decision and your business needs, but, you should not keep any data stored, in the on-line database, which is not needed any longer.

If you need to keep such data for historic report purposes then create an off-line/report database and transfer the data, periodically, from the on-line to "report" DB.

The less amount of data you have in your db the faster your RDBMS will be to retrieve/manipulate it.